# Django admin one2one list_editable in proxy model

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I need to somehow get the `is_big` field through the proxy model via the one2one link and insert it into `list_editable` in `admin.py`. I use django 3.

Here's my models.py:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()


class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.OneToOneField(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_big = models.BooleanField()


class NiceAuthor(Author):

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

And paste to `list_editable`.
Here's my admin.py:

```
class BookInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Book


class NiceAuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    inlines = [
        BookInline,
               ]

    list_display = (
        'is_big',
    )

    list_editable = (
                            # You need to insert is_big here
    )

    list_filter = (
        'book__is_big',
    )

    def big(self, obj):
        return obj.book.is_big

    big.admin_order_field = 'book__is_big'
    big.short_description = 'Book is big?'

    big.boolean = True


admin.site.register(NiceAuthor, NiceAuthorAdmin)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, используйте английский (please use english)

Comment: You might want to try to put `book__is_big` into `list_display` and `list_editable` (I don't think `is_big` in `list_display` works with your current model setup).